# using setTransactionSettings in the Authorize.net PHP API

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am trying to set the duplicateWindow time using:

```
$transactionRequestType->setTransactionSettings();
```

I found this in the PHP SDK code,

```
public function setTransactionSettings(array $transactionSettings) {...}
```

That tells me this method accepts an array, but I'm not sure how to format the data I send.

I found the XML version:

```
<transactionSettings>
   <setting>
      <settingName>duplicateWindow</settingName>
      <settingValue>0</settingValue>
  </setting>
</transactionSettings>
```

But I'm not sure how to translate that into a PHP array.

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 0):

This works if you only want to set a single setting.

I'm still trying to figure out how to set *multiple* settings (you get duplicate key issues if you try to set more than one).

```php
$transactionSettings = array(
    'setting' => array(
        'settingName' => 'duplicateWindow',
        'settingValue' => 0
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up using and it works fine.

```
$duplicateWindowSetting = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
$duplicateWindowSetting->setSettingName("duplicateWindow");
$duplicateWindowSetting->setSettingValue("120");

$transactionRequestType->addToTransactionSettings($duplicateWindowSetting);
```

To add multiple new settings, it would be pretty similar, just making a new instance of class SettingType() for each different setting you wanted.

Something like:

```
//add the values for each setting
$duplicateWindowSetting = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
$duplicateWindowSetting->setSettingName("duplicateWindow");
$duplicateWindowSetting->setSettingValue("600");

$allowPartialAuthSetting = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
$allowPartialAuthSetting->setSettingName("allowPartialAuth");
$allowPartialAuthSetting->setSettingValue("true");
```

and so on, then adding each transaction setting to the transaction request by doing something like:

```
$transactionRequestType->addToTransactionSettings($duplicateWindowSetting);
$transactionRequestType->addToTransactionSettings($allowPartialAuthSetting);
```